# Algorithm, pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I tried several times how to write a **algorithm** and a **pseudo code** for a program of finding the largest value among 3 user input integers? . I couldn't make it properly. Can i be helped?

Comment: what you tried..add something.

Comment: @Alien  i assumed that user inputs are x,y,z then if x>y then again checked the condition x>z if it is true, x is the largest. While x>y , z>y and then there is an anther condition if z>x then z is the largest number. Like wise i tried. It's hard to check conditions likewise.

Comment: Edit your question and add own pseudocode - seems you realize what to do but doubt in details.

Comment: Why do you think that finding the largest out of three integers is different than finding the largest out of, say, eleven integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pseudocode** for maximum of **3** integers-

```
print max(max(first_integer,second_integer),third_integer)
```

Comment: I think i didn't get this. Not clear enough to understand to me

Comment: What was hard though?

Comment: i didn't get what happens with this code. max(max(first_integer, second_integer), third_integer)

Comment: `max(a,b)` finds maximum between `a` and `b`

Comment: Aha. . I got it now. Thankz

Answer (score 2):

So you have three numbers, x, y, and z. You want the largest one. So here are some rules:

1. If x > y, then the largest can't be y; it must be x or z. So check to see if x > z.
2. If x < y, then the largest can't be x; it must be y or z. So check to see if y > z.

That results in the code:

```
if (x > y)
    if (x > z)
        largest = x;
    else
        largest = z;
else // y >= x
    if (y > z)
        largest = y;
    else
        largest = z;
```

If you have a `max` function that returns the maximum of two numbers, then you can simplify that code:

```
largest = max(x, y);
largest = max(largest, z);
```

Which can further be optimized to `largest = max(max(x, y), z);`

Comment: Ok. Thankz. it has been explained well. i will try to think like this way.